# React stateless functional components defaultProps function

Tags: reactjs

React 0.14 introduced [stateless functional components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions).

> you may still specify `.propTypes` and `.defaultProps` by setting them as properties on the function

However, I want to initialize one of the props to a random value (per instance) if it's not set. I can't do that if `defaultProps` only accepts an object. Is there a way to initialize it using a function, or do I have to create a full React component?

Comment: Just put `var value = props.value || randomValue();` in your function?

Comment: @FelixKling Is it not possible to change the props without re-instantiating the component? Because if the component is re-rendered I want it to use the same value. But if stateless functional components are *never* re-rendered, then that would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get this done is to set the default prop as the random value as Andrew stated.

```
Component.defaultProps = { 
  someProp: randomValue 
}
```

If it's set, this default gets overridden, so it works for the behavior you described.

If you want to set the default value using a function, it's basically the same assignment.

```
Component.defaultProps = { 
  someProp = fxnRandomValue()
}
```

EDIT:

To make sure all instance truly randomize the value of this prop, I would suggest you skip setting a default prop altogether and do the assignment within the component. Eg.

```
const statelessComp = ({ prop }) => {
  prop = prop || fxnRandomValue();
  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear. I want a random value for each instance. The value won't change after the component is rendered for the first time, but each instance needs its own unique value. I'm pretty sure your solution will create one value for all instances.

Comment: Not necessarily. That would depend on your how your randomize function works. The `defaultProps` get called every time the function wants to create each instance. However, you could choose to do the assignment within the function if you're worried it might not be random elsewhere.

Comment: `prop = prop || fxnRandomValue()` will cause it to get a different random value on every re-render, no? It should be fixed after its instantiated for the first time. Also `Component.defaultProps` is a static property, not a function, so it's not "called" ever.

Comment: After it's initiated the first time, then `prop` will be defined the next time that function will be rendered. Therefore, the only time a different random value will be assigned will be the first time, before any value is assigned at all.

Comment: How will it be defined on the next call? When you write `prop = prop || fxnRandomValue()` you're just setting a local variable. How is that preserved?

Comment: True point. I assumed too much. You could always pass in a callback that gets called from the child and sets some state with the random value. If the child needs to keep a unique state, then maybe the child shouldn't be stateless.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `recompose` library, you could achieve a solution like this:

```
import { withState } from "recompose";

var enhance = withState("someProp", "updateSomeProp", (props) => props.someProp || randomValue());
var MyComponent = enhance(function(props) {
  // This is your stateless component.
  return <div>{props.someProp}</div>;
});
```

This basically creates a wrapper component that contains a state. The state is initialized with a random value if the `someProp` is undefined.